# Issue with Groupby function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I am trying to take a dataframe, which has timestamps and various other fields, and group by rounded timestamps (to the nearest minute), and take the average of another field.  I'm getting the error `no numeric value to aggregate`

I am rounding the timestamp column like such:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.round('1min')
```

The aggregation column is of the form: `0 days 00:00:00.054000`

```
df3 = (
    df
    .groupby([df['time']])['total_diff'].mean()
    .unstack(fill_value=0)
    .reset_index()
)
```

I realize the total_diff column is a time delta field, but I would have thought this would still be considered numerical?

My ideal output would have the following columns: Rounded timestamp, number of records that are grouped in that timestamp, average total_diff by rounded timestamp.  How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**
Example row:

```
[index, id, time, total_diff]
[400, 5fdfe9242c2fb0da04928d55, 2020-12-21 00:16:00, 0 days 00:00:00.055000]
[401, 5fdfe9242c2fb0da04928d56, 2020-12-21 00:16:00, 0 days 00:00:00.01000]
[402, 5fdfe9242c2fb0da04928d57, 2020-12-21 00:15:00, 0 days 00:00:00.05000]
```

The time column is not unique.  I want to group by the time column, count the number of rows that are grouped into each time bucket, and produce an average of the total_diff for each time bucket.

Desired outcome:

```
[time, count, avg_total_diff]
[2020-12-21 00:16:00, 2, .0325]
```

Comment: Please share sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 3):

By default [`DataFrame.groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) has `numeric_only=True`, and numeric **only** considers `int`, `bool` and `float`. To also work with `timedelta64[ns]` you must set this to `False`
.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='2T', periods=6))
df[1] = df[0].diff().bfill()
#                    0               1
#0 2010-01-01 00:00:00 0 days 00:02:00
#1 2010-01-01 00:02:00 0 days 00:02:00
#2 2010-01-01 00:04:00 0 days 00:02:00
#3 2010-01-01 00:06:00 0 days 00:02:00
#4 2010-01-01 00:08:00 0 days 00:02:00
#5 2010-01-01 00:10:00 0 days 00:02:00

df.dtypes
#0     datetime64[ns]
#1    timedelta64[ns]
#dtype: object
```

#### Code

```
df.groupby(df[0].round('5T'))[1].mean()
#DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

df.groupby(df[0].round('5T'))[1].mean(numeric_only=False)
#0
#2010-01-01 00:00:00   0 days 00:02:00
#2010-01-01 00:05:00   0 days 00:02:00
#2010-01-01 00:10:00   0 days 00:02:00
#Name: 1, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: I think `resample` could be direct than rounding + `groupby`

Comment: @ALollz How can I include the number of rows per group?  Then the answer will be perfect.

Comment: @PaulH yeah probably, was just reproducing whatever the OP did. `resample` doesn't fix the issue as it's basically equivalent to `groupby` and the issue is with `GroupBy.mean`, which doesn't change.

Comment: @StormsEdge, a possible way to get the count as well: `df.groupby('time').agg(Mean=('total_diff', lambda x: x.mean(numeric_only=False)), Count=('total_diff', 'count'))`.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva Thanks!

Comment: @StormsEdge yup, and not sure if the `lambda` winds up being super slow compared to the built in. If that's the case you can always concat the result of that with `.groupby('size')`. Though it's a lot more code, it can be a lot more performant to ditch the lambdas.

Comment: Took me a long time to figure this out, but if you want to do this in a aggregate function. 
`from pandas.core.series import Series 

df.groupby('group_by_column').agg( 
column_name = ('mean_column',lambda x: Series(x).mean(numeric_only=False))
)`